# will jvm allocate 5G RAm if Xms5120m

Tags: java, memory, jvm

We have a java process which has such start argument: -Xms5120m -Xmx5120M

Will jvm allocate 5G RAM at the startup?

Is it a good practice compared with -Xms1024m -Xmx5120M?

[UPDATE]

Even if I set Xms5120M, it seems to be ignored. When the process starts, Task manager show it only used about 2G RAM. Why is that?

Comment: How about the second question?

Comment: Are you running 32bit or 64bit Java?

Answer (score 0):

java will only allocate what is needed at the time. when you tell it u want -Xmx5G that is telling the computer at max. while xms is minimum system memory. If the initial memory heap dose not exceed the 5G but instead uses 2G the task manager is simply telling you that the 2G of memory is in use but dose not show your allocations. this goes to show that ur memory heap did not consume the full 5G of allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the initial heap memory to be initialized immediately, you probably can try the `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` JVM option:

> Pre-touch the Java heap during JVM initialization. Every page of the heap is thus demand-zeroed during initialization rather than incrementally during application execution.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html